# how to write into an xml using vbscript

Tags: xml, vbscript, fciv

how to write in an xml file using vbscript???
I want to print the size and type of various files into an xml file and list it. how do I do it?

for example: folder E has 3 files. so wanna write a program such tht the program checks folder E, and lists the size and type of all files in it to an xml file

pls help

below is the program I have written to copy all the files of a folder to a text file.. but I want to copy to an xml

```vb
Option Explicit
Dim objFSO,objf,objfolder, objFile, strFileProperties, strFiles,OBJFLD,objfile2
dim objf1,objfile1,objtextfile,strfolderproperties,objsubfld


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objf= objFSO.Getfolder("C:\Test")
set OBJFLD=objf.subfolders

for each objfolder in OBJFLD

    strFolderproperties = strFolderproperties & "Number of files: " & objFolder.Files.Count & VbCrLf

    set objfile2=objfolder.files
    for each objfile in objfile2

        ' Display generel file properties
        strFileProperties = strFileProperties & "File name: " & objFile.Name & VbCrLf
        strFileProperties = strFileProperties & "File path: " & objFile.Path & VbCrLf
        strFileProperties = strFileProperties & "File size: " & objFile.Size & " bytes" & VbCrLf
        strFileProperties = strFileProperties & "File type: " & objFile.Type & VbCrLf & vbcrlf
     next
next


set objf1=objfso.getfolder("E:\logs3")
set objfile1=objfso.getfile( "E:\logs3\database.txt")

set objf1=nothing
set objfile1=nothing

set objtextfile=objfso.opentextfile("E:\logs3\database.txt",8,true)

objtextfile.writeline(strfileproperties)
objtextfile.close

set objf1=objfso.getfolder("E:\logs3")
set objfile1=objfso.getfile( "E:\logs3\database.txt")

set objf1=nothing
set objfile1=nothing


set objsubfld=objfso.opentextfile("E:\logs3\database.txt",8,true)
objsubfld.writeline(strfolderproperties)
objsubfld.close
```

Comment: What structure should the XML file have? What have you tried so far?

Comment: so far I have used vbscript and written a program to list all the files of a particular folder to a text file. but now I need to save it to an xml file... I don't know much abt xml files..will post tht program below

Comment: XML is a structured format, so you need to define the structure. What should the result look like?

Comment: A Beginner's Guide to the XML DOM http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx

Answer (score 0):

As you mention `fciv`, you can use that program to determine the **structure** and **content** of your .xml file. Even when called with -r, `fciv` will create a flat list of FILE_ENTRYs - do you need a hierarchical structure? For each file, `fciv` adds path and signature elements - what exactly is the type info you mention? - should it encoded as element or attribute? - what else do you want to know about a file?

Your specs should probably unequivocally fixed in a schema (.xsd) file.

Whether you decide to change/append to the .xml file created by `fciv`, or to create the file from scratch, you need a [XML Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms756987%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) . Use that to .load the modified `fciv` file resp. to create/append the standard 'headers', the reference to your .xsd, and a suitable root element.

Changing means looping over all FILE_ENTRY nodes and appending child elements and/or attributes.

Creating a tree should be done with a function/sub that takes a parent node (folder element) and a folder. For each file in the folder a child node (file element, with suitable children/attributes) should be added. For Each subfolder, create a new folder element and send that (with the subfolder) recursively to the function/sub.

When all is done, .save the document.

Comment: ok.. will try doing as u said.. I am totally new to this language..therefore, finding difficulties while programing.. thanks a lot for the help

Comment: i want to know the size of each file(xx kb or xx mb etc)  and the type of file (eg:exe,txt,etc)